# SSRS Email Subscription Not working

Tags: email, reporting-services, subscriptions

I'm trying to set up a couple of email delivery subscriptions to send out a few reports.

I have 1 fully working subscription that emails out every day at the same time. How ever if i try to create any more it fails. If i change the name of the report (with the working subscription) in any way it then fails until i undo any name changes that have been done.

Do i need to configure each report (the first subscription was already set up for me.)

I have tried making the new subscriptions but each time get a fail to send message.

Comment: Do you have any details from the reporting services error log that you can share?

Comment: all im seeing is

Comment: rsServerConfigurationError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use a shared data source you will need to configure the data connection report by report.
Also, you need to set up the subscription one-by-one.

If you have access, try to run a query for the execution log for more detailed information.

```
    USE ReportServer
    GO
    
    SELECT *
    FROM ExecutionLogStorage
```

Comment: Found a slight issue ,

Comment: I can generate the email and it sends , however as soon as i click include report it then fails.

Comment: Can you please check if the account runs reporting services has the right for creating files on the server? My suggestion is that filestream capability is needed to generate then include the report. Which format applies?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue and the solution to my problem was due to sqlreporter (the login SQL Server gave for the SSRS subscriptions) did not have the proper credentials.

To solve this, I needed to permit `EXECUTE` and `SQLAgentUserRole` on `msdb`. Not sure if the agent role permission was necessary but I figured it was since the subscriptions are jobs owned by the sqlreporter login.